# Pulling out domain classes from a Spring Roo project

Tags: maven, spring-roo, spring-batch, domain-model, multi-module

We need to be able **to pull out domain classes (i.e. entities) from a Spring Roo project** in order **to reuse them for a Spring Batch project**.

Is this possible?

Bearing in mind that we rely on Maven as our build and dependency management tool, and that our Roo project is already created, can we **switch to a multi-module architecture**?

If so how?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a roo command for converting a single module maven project to a multi module project.

One option would be to use roo to create a separate persistence module in your current project and manually migrate your entities and configuration over.